# Is $f:X^n\to X^n$ a homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space. And let $X^n$ be $\underbrace{X\times X\times\cdots \times X}_{n\text{ times}}$ with the product topology.

Let $\sigma$ be a permutation of $\{1,\cdots,n\}$. Define $f:X^n\to X^n$ as the map, $$(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\mapsto (x_{\sigma(1)},\cdots,x_{\sigma(n)})$$

It is clear that $f$ is a bijection with $f^{-1}$ given by, $$ (y_1,\cdots,y_n)\mapsto (y_{\sigma^{-1}(1)},\cdots,y_{\sigma^{-1}(n)})$$ 
But is $f$ also a homeomorphism?

Intuitively, I think it is, but I am struggling to prove it rigorously. Can anyone help?

Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest trying it first with $n=2$ and $\sigma$ the nontrivial permutation.

Comment: So if $U_1\times U_2$ is an open set in $X^2$ then $f^{-1}(U_1\times U_2)=U_2\times U_1$ which is open. Hence $f$ is continuous and similarly so is $f^{-1}$. Is that right?

Comment: Since projection and tupling are continuous, and the composition of continuous functions is continuous, the question reduces to whether $\sigma$ can be written as a composition of those functions.  In other words, we can make a language where everything we can express is continuous (if the "primitives" are) and the question, then, is whether $\sigma$ can be expressed in that language.

Comment: @DerekElkins, what is tupling?

Comment: @Rise Building a tuple from some elements, but to present it as a function, we can say it means, for functions $f : X \to Y$ and $g : X \to Z$, the function $\langle f,g \rangle(x) = (f(x), g(x))$ is continuous whenever $f$ and $g$ are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since any permutation is a composition of several transpositions, it suffices to take the case $n = 2$ with $\sigma$ not being the identity. That is, we must check that $f(x,y) = (y,x)$ is a homeomorphism. Let $U \times V \ni (y,x) = f(x,y)$ be a basic open set. Then $V\times U \ni (x,y)$ is another basic open set, and $f[V\times U] \subseteq U\times V $, so $f$ is continuous (actually we have an equality, but this is overkill). And now $f^{-1} = f$ is continuous, hence homeomorphism.